# Bash парсинг результата команды

Tags: php, linux, парсер, bash

Привет, сколько ищу- не могу найти ответ на решение вопроса.
Имеется баш скрипт, который запускается с помощью php(связывается с CMS), при запуске он (bash скрипт) выдает результат в виде

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
                      I M P O R T A N T
------------------------------------------------------------------
                Account created
         loginname= "login", password= "password"
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Каким образом можно отпарсить значения loginname и password с помощью того же пхп ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверял код, но должно отработать:

```
function getCredentials($input, $output) {
    preg_match('/'.$input.'=\s"(.*?)"/', $output, $matches);

    if(empty($matches[1])) {
        return null;
    }

    return $matches[1];
}

$output = shell_exec('command');

$login = getCredentials('loginname', $output);
$passsword = getCredentials('passsword', $output);
```

Функция принимает атрибут и вывод консоли и находит значение.

Или же можно всё сделать чуть иначе:

```
function getCredentials($output) {
    preg_match_all('/=\s"(.*?)"/', $output, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);

    if(empty($matches[1])) {
        return null;
    }

    return $matches[1];
}
```

Но в таком случае не понятно что в итоге может придти в ответе, в идеале должен быть ответ:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "login"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "password"
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за слишком долгий ответ. Решение помогло, спасибо!